# mysql compare select result with a set of values

Tags: mysql, sql, compare

i have two tables, 
one contains the person_id and name of a person_name
the second table contains and auto increment relative_id, person_id and relative_name

```
person_id------person_name
--------------------------
--------------------------

relative_id-----person_id------relative_name
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------
```

i have a set of names (adam, carl, dave,....)

how can i get the names of persons who all their relatives names are in that set( their relative are subset of the set of names)

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Are you really storing names in two different tables?

Answer (score 0):

Do join & aggregation :

```
select p.person_name
from person p inner join
     person_relative pr
     on pr.person_id = p.person_id
where pr.relative_name in ('adam', 'carl', 'dave')
group by p.person_name
having count(*) = 3;
```

If single person has duplicate relatives then use `distinct` inside `count()` :

```
having count(distinct pr.relative_name) = 3;
```

**EDIT :** After question edit were made

```
select p.person_name
from person p inner join
     person_relative pr
     on pr.person_id = p.person_id
group by p.person_name
having sum( pr.relative_name not in ('adam', 'carl', 'dave') ) = 0;
```